# No hardware "Options" button , How to get option menu to appear?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this:  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`.
The menu works fine with devices that comes with a "hardware options button" at the bottom ,menu items appear as expected on the bottom of the screen .

How to make the "Options" button appears with a device that doesn't have this "hardware button"?

What I am looking for :

[See the screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51018887/illustration.png)

If I disabled the (Fullscreen) style the menu show up at the upper right corner ,as expected too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "button" you are referring to in your screenshot is only available if your application has a target SDK value below 11 in your manifest, because it is a compatibility trick for applications that expect a device with a hardware menu button and haven't been update to use an Action Bar menu.

If you use an Action Bar menu, the expectation is that you do not hide it from the user (at least no permanently).

Comment: Wow !! you are absolutely right ! I tried to lower my SDK target below "11" and it worked , I wasn't expecting an answer like that. Thanks a lot . I am suer this wasn't an easy to find answer but defiantly your expert is the reason , and as I see your "Reputation precedes you" .

Comment: So what do you suggest? , disabling the full screen and stay on the highest SDK , or keep going on "10" SDK and benefit the awesome  full screen ,  I tried the application on my IceCream Sandwich and it worked fine .

Comment: @K-19, although I am not sure if this trick works with full screen theme, maybe you can add a custom button and hook it to `openOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: I found this after a long search : http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html . It conforms what Devunwired says.

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the `ActionBar` which contains the `menu` items when using this line

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

I'm not sure why you are doing this but if you want them to show then don't use this `Theme`

Comment: Yes, you're right , I did that on purpose , full screen is better looking sometimes and offers more space to play with ,why not?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the target SDK on your Manifest xml file to target SDK 10:

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"  android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

And you'll get the three dots circular menu button on the bottom right.

Also note that You'll find a problem on google play when  updating apk, google won't let you downgrade to lower targetSdkVersion